# Missing library for glShaderModel in my native C++ Android program

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I am not certain what library I need to add for this error:

```
../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/PhysicsLessons/PhysicsLessons.o: in function 
engine_handle_cmd(android_app*, int):jni/PhysicsLessons.cpp:104: error: undefined reference to 'glShadeModel'
```

In Android.mk I have this:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -lEGL -lGLESv2 -llog -landroid 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
```

And in Application.mk I am `APP_PLATFORM=android-10`

I am using ndk8e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are linking against the OpenGL ES2.0 library, which doesn't have the fixed pipeline. `glShadeModel` is not in there. Check the [gl2.h header](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/2.0/gl2.h).

Try linking against `libGLESv1_CM`

Comment: Thank you.  Now at least I have a starting point as I learn opengl es on my Android.  My first step is to have the code be v2.0. :)